# Mips - Printing game's board

Tags: assembly, mips

Hello all
I have a mips assignment which is supposed to be a flipping cards game,
so I am supposed to print a board which is 4x13

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

each * represents a card
so when I enter the row and column it should flip the card which is in that position for example

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * 5A * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

I can print the board using .ascii, but how am I going to flip a card every time I choose a position
how to flip the star and print the value every time I enter a position?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite your stars in your .ascii data with sb (2 times, according to your example), then just reprint your data.